# Suppress Exception in Office365 powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a script which adds members of an Active Directory group to an Office 365 distribution group. Many members of the AD group will also be members of the distribution group already, which causes the script to display the error:

```
Adding user@domain.com to distribution group GROUP
The recipient "user@domain.com" is already a member of the group "GROUP".
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (user@domain.com:RecipientWithAdUserGroupIdParameter`1)
[Add-DistributionGroupMember], MemberAlreadyExistsException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=HKNPR04MB0531,RequestId=84dc77fb-8cf4-4e2f-882e-0ce66b735d08,TimeStamp=9/02/2015 6:55:13 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-MemberAlreadyExistsException] 7CEFF683,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddDistributionGroupMember
+ PSComputerName        : pod51055psh.outlook.com
```

I would like to suppress these errors, as I don't care if the members already exist.

I have tried catching the `MemberAlreadyExistsException`, setting `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and catching all errors and writing "Error!" instead of the actual exception, however this does not seem to have taken effect.

Currently, my Try-Catch block looks like this:

```
try 
{
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroupName -Member $MemberEmail
}
Catch [System.Management.Automation.RemoteException]
{
    if($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -match 'AlreadyExists')
    {
        Write-Output "`t   $emailaddress is already a member of $DistributionGroupName."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "`t $_.Exception"
    }
}
```

I believe that this should alert me when a user already exists, however I still receive an exception message.

Comment: It might not be a terminating error.  Does it work if you add -ErrorAction Stop to the Add-DitributionGroupMember cmdlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @mjolinor, I was able to catch the exception and provide a more user-friendly message. My corrected code is below:

```
try 
{
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroupName -Member $EmailAddress -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch [System.Exception]
{
    if($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -match 'AlreadyExists')
    {
        Write-Output "`t   $emailaddress is already a member of $DistributionGroupName."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "`t $_.Exception"
    }
}
```

I added the `-ErrorAction Stop` as suggested, which allowed me to `Catch` the exception. I also modified the exception type to catch all exceptions. Interestingly (in my opinion), the `Catch` block failed if I did not put an exception type in there.

Program output is now:

```
Adding user@domain.com to distribution group GROUP
user@domain.com is already a member of GROUP.
```

Comment: Running into the same problem. And your tip about having to add the exception type to the Catch is not working for me. Nor does the a plain Catch work for me. What version of Powershell are you using? I'm at  5.0.10586.63. Thanks.

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` shows that I'm using 5.0.10240.16384.